# No results in Google Maps Places Api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was building an app using the places API along with autosuggestion and I found something peculiar about the query " Kuwait Magic Mall, Al Ahmadi, Kuwait " .

The thing is that the auto suggest results show me the mall as one of the options , but when I select it , the place doesnt show up.

After a while ,when I couldnt find an answer, so I tried it on the Google Map tutorial, on 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html
but got the same result there as well.

I have asked the same question on Google Maps groups, but havent got any answer.

Comment: Do you have some running code or a JSFiddle that you can post that shows what you're doing? We can't really debug anything without actually seeing it.

Comment: Steps to reproduce: (1) go to http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html (2) type or paste "Kuwait Magic Mall, Al Ahmadi, Kuwait" (3) click on the suggestion provided (4) observe nothing happens. To be more precise, one thing happens, this request is sent out: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails?...` which returns status `NOT_FOUND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange behavior.  Will have to look into this further.

In the meantime, looks like the `autocomplete.bindTo()` method is preventing the result from showing (in the example you linked to).  If you remove the `bindTo()` call, you'll see that the example works.

Here is a JSFiddle that shows the autocomplete working with that place:

http://jsfiddle.net/qZU6L/

You could also try in the meantime to see if the autocomplete.setBounds() method works for you.

Comment: Yeah. It works alright after removing bindTo(). I couldnt understand the purpose of bindTo(), can anyone direct me to a good example for it

Comment: Per the docs at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#places_autocomplete:

To bias the results to the map's viewport, even as that viewport changes, use the Autocomplete object's `bindTo()` function.